# Can i call shell command and output of this save to string on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

In other words something like pipe in windows

Comment: Windows can pipe output just like Unix (same operator).  You'll need to be more specific with your question if you want more info than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boilerplate code is in this [MSDN Library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using [_popen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa298534%28VS.60%29.aspx).